# Object can't be converted to JSon

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5, json.net

I have this perculiar problem with a Entity Framework 5 Code First database and Json serializing.

I have a database with the following user class

```
public class User
{
    [Key()]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual Outfit ProfileOutfit { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual PoseAnimation ProfilePose { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual Mannequin ProfileMannequin { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual ICollection<int> SubscribedTo { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual ICollection<Fashionshow> Fashionshows { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual ICollection<Outfit> Outfits { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual ICollection<Snapshot> Snapshots { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual ICollection<Achievement> Achievements { get; set; }
}
```

I have this in my DbContext:

```
public class SilkDbContext9 : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<News> News { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Outfit> Outfits { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Fashionshow> Fashionshows { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sound> Sounds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Snapshot> Snapshots { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OutfitPart> OutfitParts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Mannequin> Mannequins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PoseAnimation> PoseAnimations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WalkAnimation> WalkAnimations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Achievement> Achievements { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ConstructOutfit> ConstructOutfits { get; set; }

    public DbSet<DesignOutfit> DesignOutfits { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I request the user class on a localhost environment (like debugging with visual studio) through an ApiController, it works and gives me back a list of users, or one. When I request it on the server I deploy it to however, I get the following object back:

```
{"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred."}
```

I have no idea how to get this right. I already tried removing all references to the User class from the other objects, in case there is an endless loop somewhere, but it didn't help. I also tried turning off and on this piece of code (which didn't help either):

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

I'm guessing I get the error from the converting to JSon since the error isn't catched in the get method.

In short, I have an object that does serialize into Json on a localhost but not on my IIS server. How to solve this?

### Update

I can't log it (as far as I know, I'm not really familiar with IIS) because the get method in my API seems to work. Here it is:

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetUsers()
    {
        IEnumerable<User> users;

        try
        {
            users = db.Users.AsEnumerable();
        }
        catch
        {
            return new List<string>() { "Error getting the collection" };
        }

        try
        {
            return users;
        }
        catch
        {
            return new List<string>() { "Error returning the collection" };
        }
    }
```

Since neither of the error strings are returned, I'm guessing the actual users are returned, and that the serializing to JSon is at fault. I get the users by going to /api/users.

Comment: Try to get the details of the error, log it somewhere.

Comment: You haven't shown how you're trying to request a `User` as a JSON object.

Comment: By the way `An error has occurred.` could mean a million different things, it's not necessary the JSON conversion that could be the problem.

Comment: I do know that, but it's basically all the info I have since it doesn't crash on my regular development environment and I don't know how to extract the log from IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post enough code for me to know whether this is the case or not, so this is a guess: I have seen the following problem when serializing EF entites via MVC ActionResults:

Your LINQ query needs to be fully materialized (i.e. the SQL executed and converted to entities) before the DbSet is disposed.  It is fairly easy to return an unmaterialized IQueryable as part of an ActionResult, and usually the DbSet is disposed before the Action Method returns.  This causes the query to blow up AFTER your return statement when the serializer tries to enumerate some collection in the result which causes the LINQ query to execute.

If this is your problem, the solution is to make sure your IQueryable is materialized before disposing the DbSet by calling ToList() or ToArray() on it.

Comment: Can you maybe look at the added code and see if this is the problem? I am using .AsEnumerable() before returning it.

Comment: AsEnumerable() will not cause the query to execute, you need to call ToArray() or ToList(), or execute some code that actually enumerates the IEnumerable (foreach etc.)

Comment: By the way, if you were to attach the debugger while this was happening and turn on "Break when an exception is Thrown" for CLR exceptions, you would probably see some useful info about what is going on.  This is available on the Debug | Exceptions menu.  May be impractical in production, but you could force your DbSet to dispose  on your dev machine and see whether you have the same type of error.

Comment: .ToList() worked, thanks, I still think it's weird though it did work on my development machine. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: Differences in the OS version (server vs. workstation), and hardware (number of CPU cores) can affect the timing of multithreaded things going on.  Are you letting the garbage collector clean up your DbSet or are you explicitly disposing it somewhere?  If you are leaving it up to the GC, I would expect intermittent failures like that.  If you are explicitly disposing in End_Request or something like that, that is likely happening in a different thread than the response serialization, and for whatever reason the server thread scheduler is making it happen earlier, before the serializer can run.